# GIT: dealing with pre-receive hook during merge

Tags: git, githooks

I have problem with `pre-receive` hook. My hook checks if commits pushed to the branch contain jira ticket or specific tag. And it works fine. Unfortunately, when I create Pull Request (I'm working with GitHub) and click merge I'm getting information that my commit doesn't contain a jira ticket. It look like during merge, git creates his own revision for that. My hook looks like that:

```
set -e

zero_commit='0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
msg_regex='(^\[NA\])|([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)'
branch_regex='[A-Z]+-[0-9]+'
na_tag="[NA]"
while read -r oldrev newrev refname; do
    branch=${refname#refs/heads/}
    ticket_in_branch=$(echo "${branch}" | grep -oE "$branch_regex" || echo "")
    
    # Branch or tag got deleted, ignore the push
    [ "$newrev" = "$zero_commit" ] && continue

    # Calculate range for new branch/updated branch
    [ "$oldrev" = "$zero_commit" ] && range="$newrev" || range="$oldrev..$newrev"

    for commit in $(git rev-list "$range" --not --all); do
        ticket_in_commit=$(git log --max-count=1 --format=%B $commit | grep -oE "$msg_regex" || echo "")
        if [ "$ticket_in_commit" = "$ticket_in_branch" ]
        then
            echo "Commit ${commit} already contains a [Jira ticket number] or [NA]: ${ticket_in_commit}"
        else
            if [ -z "$ticket_in_branch" ] && [ "$ticket_in_commit" = "$na_tag" ]
            then
                echo "Commit $(commit) already contains a [Jira ticket number] or [NA] tag: ${na_tag}"
            else
                echo "MESSAGE"
                echo "ERROR:"
                echo "ERROR: Your push was rejected because the commit"
                echo "ERROR: $commit in ${refname#refs/heads/}"
                echo "ERROR: is missing the JIRA Issue, for example: '[AB-1234] msg' or '[NA] msg' OR Jira Ticket Ids are not the same"
                echo "ERROR:"
                echo "ERROR: Please fix the commit message and push again."
                echo "ERROR"
                exit 1  
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

For example if my branch is `AB-1234-test-branch` and my commit `"[AB-1234] test commit"` I can push to this branch without any problem. But while merging, I'm getting information that specific commit (which I can find in my git logs) doesn't contain specific jira ticket. Is there a way to deal with this problem?

Comment: you need not to implement changelog,google about this.

Comment: @MikiBelavista not sure what you mean. I googled about changelog, but how does it connect with my problem? Maybe I'm missing/dont understand something

Comment: Maybe I got it worng. Read https://www.readysetcloud.io/blog/allen.helton/continuous-delivery-try-continuous-changelog/

Comment: It depends where you deploy.

Comment: Well, I still have no idea how it can solve my problem :D I just want to merge `dev-branch` into `main`. I have `pre-receive` hook which checks if commit messages contain the same ticket which is included in branch name. And it works perfectly fine while doing commits in my `dev-branch`. The problem comes with merge